# Buttons in corners of table-cell; text in center

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table

I want to make a 5x5 grid with words each cell. But each cell gets a button in every corner. I made a image of it:

[image: Hell yeah, mspaint-skills!]

I don't really know how to do this. How can I make these "corner-buttons" with the text in the center?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      ??
    </td>
    [..]
  </tr>
  [..]
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this is infinitely easier to achieve with CSS.

Here's a very quick & simply example of how I'd do it with one box..

```
<div class='box'>
Tree
<span class='tl_tri tri' onclick='whatever you want the button to do'></span>
<span class='tr_tri tri' onclick='whatever you want the button to do'></span>
<span class='bl_tri tri' onclick='whatever you want the button to do'></span>
<span class='br_tri tri' onclick='whatever you want the button to do'></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height:100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  line-height:100px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
.tri {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
.tl_tri {
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid green;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.tr_tri {
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid red;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
.bl_tri {
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid grey;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.br_tri {
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid yellow;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

This is demonstrated working here:

https://jsfiddle.net/0qtj0o0z/